# How to put IBActions functions inside of a method xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, function, methods, ibaction

I have methods that changes the color of textfields and UIViews when a user taps on the textfield or taps off of it. However, I don't want to keep stating IBActions over and over again throughout my code since my app will be quite large with lots of textfields. I have a separate file where I keep all of my methods that apply to every ViewController with textfields, is there any way that I can create a function in that file that contains an IBAction so I don't have to keep stating IBActions in my Viewcontroller swift files?

For example:

When a user taps on a textfield, there is a line under the textfield that turns green (the line is comprised out of a UIView).

This is located in my separate file where I keep all of my functions.

```
    static func makeBottomLineGreen(_ bottomLine:UIView, _ textField:UITextField) {
        
        func designBottomLineGreen(_ bottomLine:UIView) {
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 48/255, green: 173/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1)}, completion: nil)
        }
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.designBottomLineBlack(_:)), for: .editingDidBegin)
    }
```

I get an error "Argument of '#selector' refers to static method 'designBottomLineBlack' that is not exposed to Objective-C, Add '@objc' to expose this static method to Objective-C"

I've already tried this solution and it doesn't work.

So in my ViewController.swift file I want to use the method like this

```
makeBottomLineBlack(textField1, bottomLine1)
```

I'm doing this to avoid dragging in tons of IBActions and having redundant code. The function takes two arguments, the textfield and the bottomline that turns green so the action of tapping on the textfield makes the line under the textfield turn green.

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: check out this pod may be it will help you pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField'

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no, this is impossible. We are asking here to be called back by ObjectiveC Cocoa. It cannot see anything other than methods of classes.

> When a user taps on a textfield, there is a line under the textfield that turns green (the line is comprised out of a UIView).

Then I suggest you subclass UITextField and put the functionality in that one place — the subclass. That way you can have as many text fields as you like that perform this same functionality. That is what subclassing is for: to give multiple instances the same extra functionality.